# In Memoriam: Christopher Priest

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Christopher Priest has died](https://www.ninaallan.co.uk/?p=6855). Among other things, [he was the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Priest_(novelist)) of *The Prestige*. He actually wrote back to me about [my question about whether the body was always dead after the transfer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177956/within-the-novel-the-prestige-was-were-the-prestige-materials-always-inert).

Comment: Priest wrote *Inverted World*, which is _at least_ as notable as *The Prestige*.